# Handlebars templates not appearing

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to add an item to a list with the item's title being equal to what the user entered in a text box using Handlebars to handle the templating and changing the display title to whatever the user entered.

When the user clicks the button, the actual list item is being added, but the title is not being displayed according to my handlebars template.

Here is my HTML:

```
<section id="list" class="hidden">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns center-text">
            <h1>Bukkitt</h1>
            <p>Add your bucket list items below...</p>
            <input id="newItem" class="input center-text" type="text"/> <br>
            <a id="addButton" href="#"><i id="add" class="icon-plus-circled"></i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="eight columns center-text">
            <h1>Your Bucket List...</h1>
                <ul class="list">
                    <script id="list-items" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                        {{#each this}}
                        <li>
                            <h3>{{name}}</h3>
                            <ul class="helperSites">
                                <li><img src="{{helpers}}" alt=""/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </script>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And my JS:

```
function Item(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.helpers = [];
}

var allItems = [];

function Helper(site) {
    this.site = site
};

Item.prototype = {
    constructor: Item,
    addHelper:function(site) {
        new Helper(site);
        this.helpers[length-1]
    }
};


//New Item Button
var newItem = document.getElementById("newItem");
$('#addButton').click(function(){
     var item = new Item(newItem.value);
     allItems.push(item);
    console.log(allItems);

        var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#list-items').html() );
        var temp = template(allItems);
        $('ul.list-items').append(temp);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').append(temp);
```

fixes the problem